# Android open the Gmail attachement using my app

Tags: android, gmail

How to open the Gmail attachement using my app which is developed to print.
I am not getting the path of Gmail attachement downloaded path.I am getting empty path. Please share the code snipets.
thanks in advance

here is my intenet filter code

```
 <intent-filter
            android:label="@string/intent_lable_print" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.action.PRINT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" />                    
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: just make an intent filter in your manifest

Comment: please correct if anything wrong in my intent filter